# Run Stored Procedure From Page Load

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-3.4, sql

I have a html table that has a hyperlink in it, when the hyperlink is pressed 3 parameters are passed to a secondary page.  The query that is run is a `CTE` SQL Server statement, and from my understanding the wonderful app `sourcerer` can not handle these type statements, so I am using a stored procedure.

What is the proper way to run a SQL Server Stored Procedure from page load in a Joomla Article?  I know how to run the stored procedure from the article, just not sure of how to have it execute from the page load.  Ideally have the hyperlink be a 2 step process

1) Run Stored Procedure

2) redirect
However if that is not possible, how would I run the stored procedure from page load?

(The procedure must take the parameters that are passed which is why I can not have it pre-load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sourcerer can in fact run a CTE query.  Just set it up as a long query string as if you were going to run inline sql in SSMS.  Like this:

```
//Database Connection Info
$db = JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = ";WITH CTE AS ..... rest of query";
$db->setQuery($query); 
$query = $db->loadObjectList();
//Spit out results however you need
```